# Why is Dominion referred as ODIN?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've been poking around the API and it seems that Dominion is always referred as 'ODIN'. Its the only mode that has a name that doesn't seem to fit the final name of the gametype.

Is there any known reason for this?

PS: Here's a link to the API. https://developer.riotgames.com/docs/game-constants

Comment: This sounds awful close to a, "Why did they design it that way" type of question...

Comment: It's close, but I guess the answer we are looking for is what was the original developpement name of the Dominion Gamemode.

Comment: Which is still asking for developer intent, is it not?

Comment: Well, check out the other names. Doom Bots are Nightmare Bots, Nemesis is COUNTERPICK and so on. I just think they develop it with a name, then the PR Guys are like: "Nah, we can't call it that way" and just rename it. The internal name stays the same because its usually not important for the guys not in the development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ODIN was simply a code name for the Crystal Scar while it was in development](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2688200&page=45#post30328369).

Riot never stated why they called it ODIN but apparently they havent changed the name.

Some fan theories suggest that it has something to do with Odyn's Valley which is the original home of the Bracken (Skarner's kind) and it's also close to the Crystal Scar on the Map. However this is not confirmed by riot so take it with a grain of salt.